# Most idiomatic way to handle API keys in a Rust library?

Tags: binding, rust, idioms

I am working on writing Rust bindings for an API that takes in two API keys. There are numerous ways to accomplish this. I specifically do not want to burden the user with making requests like

```
myapi::requestThing(firstApiKey, SecondApiKey,...)
```

I would like to have the user only pass in the API keys once and have it remember it. The problem is I'm trying to do this functionally, and cramming everything into a struct also doesn't seem like the best way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You absolutely do not want to have some sort of global configuration that is magically stored. That would prevent the API being used by multiple users concurrently in the same process.

I would construct a builder for the API endpoint. This can provide defaults for the API URL and can also grab API keys from the environment variables. You can also override the URL or keys programmatically.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct ApiEndpoint {
    url: String,
    api_key_1: String,
    api_key_2: String,
}

impl ApiEndpoint {
    fn add_money_to_account(&self, cents: u64) {
        println!("Adding {} cents. Making a request to {} ({}, {})", cents, self.url, self.api_key_1, self.api_key_2);
    }
}

struct ApiBuilder {
    url: Option<String>,
    api_key_1: Option<String>,
    api_key_2: Option<String>,
}

impl ApiBuilder {
    fn new() -> ApiBuilder {
        ApiBuilder {
            url: None,
            api_key_1: None,
            api_key_2: None,
        }
    }

    fn url(mut self, url: &str) -> ApiBuilder {
        self.url = Some(url.into());
        self
    }

    fn api_key_1(mut self, api_key_1: &str) -> ApiBuilder {
        self.api_key_1 = Some(api_key_1.into());
        self
    }

    fn api_key_2(mut self, api_key_2: &str) -> ApiBuilder {
        self.api_key_2 = Some(api_key_2.into());
        self
    }

    fn build(self) -> ApiEndpoint {
        let mut env_vars: HashMap<_, _> = std::env::vars().collect();

        ApiEndpoint {
            url: self.url.unwrap_or_else(|| "http://example.com/default".into()),
            api_key_1: self.api_key_1.or_else(|| env_vars.remove("MYLIB_ENV_VAR_1")).unwrap(),
            api_key_2: self.api_key_2.or_else(|| env_vars.remove("MYLIB_ENV_VAR_2")).unwrap(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let endpoint =
        ApiBuilder::new()
        .url("https://test.example.com")
        .api_key_1("SEEKRET")
        .api_key_2("PASSWORD")
        .build();

    endpoint.add_money_to_account(500);
}
```

> cramming everything into a struct also doesn't seem like the best way

I don't see why not.